# Refactoring my DataTable search code

Tags: c#, search, refactoring

I am using C# 2.0, and I can't help but think this isn't the most efficient way to search a collection (in this case a DataTable) for a value:

```
bool found = false;
foreach (DataRow row in data.Rows)
{
    if (id == row["rowID"])
    {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found)
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Can anyone think of a "cleaner" way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the datatable's `Select()` method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5c0xc84(VS.80).aspx

```
DataRow[] rows = data.Select("rowID=" + id.ToString());
if (rows.Length > 0)
{
    //Do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a linear search and it is the slowest actual search there is.

One alternative, if you want to continue using a DataTable, is to define a primary key and use the Find() method:

```
myTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("rowID") };
DataRow row = myTable.Find(id);
```